# How to deal with sibling inheritance problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, oop, ecmascript-6

I have a base class that deals with finding/saving items. To reduce the `save` function complexity (since it uses `insert` or `update` depending on whether it's been saved), I thought it best to split it into two classes since a lot of my other methods (not written here) depends on whether or not it's been saved. This is a bare-bones example:

```js
class ItemBase {
  constructor (initData) {
    this.data = initData
  }

  find (id) {
    const found = Model.find(this.data)
    return new SavedItemBase(found)
  }

  save () {
    const saved = this.insert(this.data)
    return new SavedItemBase(saved)
  }

  insert () {}
  update () {}
}
```

```js
class SavedItemBase extends ItemBase {
  save () {
    this.update()
    return this
  }
}
```

Toy:

```js
class Toy extends ItemBase {
  constructor () {
    this.name = 123
    this.id = 456
  }

  someMethod () {} // This is lost if I return a new SavedItemBase
}
```

The problem with Toy is that it *only* extends `Item`. If I return a `new SavedItem` in the parent class `Item`, the original `Toy` class is lost. Here is a picture of my problem:

[image]

How would I get the Toy to return a `SavedItemBase` instance of itself when it's returned from `Base`, *without* rewriting class for `Toy` (e.g. `SavedToyBase`)? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: So, you want `SavedItemBase` to be in a toy object inheritance chain only if it has been saved? So when first created, a toy is not a `SavedItemBase`?

Comment: Yes exactly - I want to get `SavedItemBase` of a `Toy` *after* I've saved it, or when I `find` it. The `ItemBase` (and the `Toy` that inherited it) is essentially a blueprint that has not been saved to any database

Comment: `Save(thisToy)`   and `find(theToy)`   - can this work?  Breaking out *functionality* as a separate class OK, it's done all the time - but not as part of the inheritance chain.  This has the added benefit of decoupling the object classes from the database.

Comment: As a matter of "toy domain" design, a `SavedItemBase` doesn't make sense to me (given the simplified code here).  It does make sense as a defined state of a `Toy` object. So have a `ItemBase.isSaved` property or method.

Comment: *...is essentially a blueprint*.  Does its saved state make it a "blueprint" or change it from a "blueprint"?  Then the `Toy` API should express making/converting it to a blueprint. The fact that `save()` makes this so is an implementation detail and should not be substituted/hide/override  correct Toy domain modeling.

Comment: I see, right now I have exactly that (a `isSaved`) method but testing it was a bit of a pain with having two branches in multiple methods with this check. I thought splitting it into two classes would fix that, while also having the added benefit of a clear distinction between data that's saved and unsaved, but I guess not. Thank you

Comment: yes, how I have it is the unsaved state has `this.data` to be plain object, and the saved state has `this.data` to be a [mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose) class representing the DB data). I plan to use this same structure for multiple models other than Toy, which is why `save` is in `ItemBase`. There's only one direction where I go from unsaved (blueprint) to a saved state

Comment: @platizin I would suggest using composition instead of inheritance here. `Toy` (which might subclass `Item`, but not necessarily) should have a `.data` property that holds either an `ItemData` instance or a `SavedItemData` instance. They both should implement the same `Data` interface, there should be no inheritance relationship between them.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks!